# How can I edit Javascript of a website like in CSS Pivot?

Tags: web, javascript, debug

I want to edit and run Javascript on a website. Then, I'd like to save it for re-accessing it later. What I'm describing is exactly like [CSS Pivot](http://www.csspivot.com), but only for Javascript. Sharing with others is not a must though.

[jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net) is not as easy to use because simply copying the source of a website and pasting it to jsfiddle.net will not work (due to relative paths).

Comment: Are you familiar with [userscripts](http://userscripts.org/)?

Comment: No but i have not seen such a functionality when i try it.

Comment: i think it will be clearer if you try csspivot.

Comment: I have tried it, but do you absolutely need the functionality of sharing this with others?

Comment: No, sharing is not "must".